# Extjs 6: what does 'onClassExtended' do when defining a class?

Tags: javascript, extjs

```
Ext.define('Algo.data.Simulated', {
    requires: [
        //....
    ],

    onClassExtended: function (cls, data) {
        // ....
    }
})
```

Here is the code. I cannot find any documentation about it on Sencha's website.
Also, what do cls and data mean?

Comment: Put a breakpoint on the first line of the `onClassExtended` function body and check the caller.

Answer (score 3):

**Well, the easy way to find out would be to define a new class, override onClassExtended, and use two `console.log` to log the values.**

But let's take the hard way, searching the ExtJS codebase for `onClassExtended`. Notepad++ does provide a search that can find a string in all files in a directory, that's really useful with ExtJS.

You will find that the property is first processed in `packages\core\src\class\Class.js`, l. 347 ff., and that the processing does nothing but add the function to `$onExtended`. 
So we search for `$onExtended`, finding that usually, `$onExtended` is called in `triggerExtended()`, which is called from, you guess it, `packages\core\src\class\Class.js`, l. 347 ff. (but it is called BEFORE the current class's `onClassExtended` is added to the list!)

```
Class.triggerExtended.apply(Class, arguments);
```

together with

```
function(Class, data, hooks) {
```

means that `cls` will contain whatever is in `Class`, and `data` will contain whatever `data` has been put into the extend method.

Looking at the code, I believe that these two parameters are the two parameters of `Ext.define`:

```
Ext.define(
   'MyApp.data.Test', // <- Class
    { // data object
       extend:'Ext.class.Base' // <- "data.extend" is deleted in line 357
       ...
    }
);
```

It seems `onClassExtended` does allow you to define, in EVERY class in a hierarchy, a processing directive that can transform the class definition. They are executed, beginning with the topmost (the most special class) and ripple through until they reach the base class, `Ext.class.Base`.

Unlike the constructor, these transformations are executed during definition of a child class, not during instance creation.